# metric inducing a topology on the given set

Tags: general-topology

Does any metric $d$ always induce a topology on any given set $X$?

Comment: Yes. Open sets are unions of open balls in the metric.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "topology induced by a metric"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409687/what-is-the-topology-induced-by-a-metric) (and there are many more)

Comment: I think my question was different from theirs. I have read that one and many others. But no one asked whether or not any metric induced a topology on any set. I was thinking there might me some crazy metrics that I cannot think of now, which might not be able to induce a topology on some sets. Unless I am completely misunderstanding some fundamental stuff, that make my question identical to others (which is very much a possibility, I have learned about metrics fairly recently), my question must be quite different in essence.

Comment: Stack Exchange takes some getting used to, and being put on hold (for duplicate or otherwise) is reversible. When a question is closed as a "duplicate", it really means that answers there also answer your question. If you feel they don't, you can *edit your question*, cite the proposed dupe, and explain how it doesn't seem to answer your question. You should also refine and clarify your *question itself* to make this more clear, rather than only in a comment. Once you do this it will go back into a review queue and may be reopened.

Comment: Also helpful [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) and especially [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) I don't have to (at) you because this is your post, but if you want someone to receive a notification that you have directed a comment to them, you (at) their username. Usually you will see an autocomplete appear as soon as you start typing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a topology $\tau$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$, i.e. a collection of subsets which are deemed to be "open".

In a metric space $(X,d)$, you have the concept of an open set defined as follows:

> Call $A\subseteq X$ open, if for every point $a\in A$, there is a radius $r>0$ such that the open ball with radius $r$ around $x$, i.e. $B_r(x)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<r\}$, is contained in $A$, i.e. $B_r(x)\subseteq A$.

Now, you can take the topology $\tau_d$ induced by the metric $d$ to be

$$\tau_d=\{A\subseteq X\mid A\text{ is open w.r.t }d\}=\{A\subseteq X\mid \forall a\in A:\exists r>0:B_r(x)\subseteq A\}$$

and you can verify easily that $(X,\tau_d)$ fulfills the properties of a topological space.